# Keras: Embadding on Sentences Array as Input

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, word-embedding

I am new to keras. I try to create a neural network with an embedding layer as input layer. As far as I understand it right now the structure is like the following:

```
model.add(Embedding(word_count,embedding_size,input_length=sentence_length).
```

This works with a dataset of labelled sentences.

Now I want to change the structure of my dataset. I will have labelled sets of sentences (arrays of sentences).

As far as I know, I can't use the Embedding layer anymore as input layer. This is because it expects a sentence as input and not an array of sentences. Can I change something so that I still can use the embedding layer in my model but have arrays of sentences as input?

The array length of my arrays of sentences is all the time the same as my sentence length stays the same overall sentences.

Comment: The input shape of an Embedding layer is `(batch_size, input_length)` where `input_length` can be `None` (with the condition that you don't use a Flatten or Dense layer immediately after that). What's your use-case that you need to pass an array of sentences? Are they related to each other, i.e. sentences of a paragraph or a same piece of text? If that's the case then why don't you pass them as one big vector, specially when all of your sentences have the same length which makes handling them much easier in the following layers? If my words seems a bit vague, let me know to give an example.

Comment: @today I want to pass an array of sentences because one array is directed to one user. So I want to pass the input of one user. How would it look like to have a big array, can you give an example pleas? Thank you so much already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have arrays of fixed-length sentences and, as you mentioned, the number of sentences in all arrays are the same. Therefore, if you store all of your data in one tensor it would have a shape of `(num_of_arrays, num_of_sentences, length_of_sentence)`. And each array of sentences has its own label. So basically your model should take an array of sentences as an input and predicts a label for it. Now to use an embedding layer we first reshape our data, then pass it to an embedding layer and then (if necessary) we reshape it back. Here is an example:

```
from keras import models, layers

# the following numbers are just for demonstration
vocab_size = 1000
embed_dim = 50

num_arrays = 100
num_sentences = 200
len_sentence = 300

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(layers.Reshape((num_sentences*len_sentence,), input_shape=(num_sentences, len_sentence)))
model.add(layers.Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim, input_length=num_sentences*len_sentence))
model.add(layers.Reshape((num_sentences, len_sentence, embed_dim)))
# add whatever layers as you wish to complete your model

model.summary()
```

Here is the model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
reshape_1 (Reshape)          (None, 60000)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 60000, 50)         50000     
_________________________________________________________________
reshape_2 (Reshape)          (None, 200, 300, 50)      0         
=================================================================
Total params: 50,000
Trainable params: 50,000
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see, each of the sentences in an array is now represented by a matrix of shape `(sentence_length, embed_dim)`. Now you can add more layers to complete your model. I am not sure if this is what you asked for. Let me know in the comments if you meant something else.